# UITableViewCell public function not executing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

```
var list = [String]()
@IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.title = "Routines"
    TableView.delegate = self
    TableView.dataSource = self
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
//refresh view when going back to this viewcontroller
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print("Test Worked")
    TableView.reloadData()
}
//generating rows
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return (list.count)
}

//returning text in UITableViewCell
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style:
            UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:
        "prototype1")
        print("printed")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
//deleting rows
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete{
            deleteAllData("ToDo")
            self.list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            TableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
@IBAction func didAdd() {
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "addRoutinePage")as! addRoutinePage
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}

//function to get data from core data
func getData()
{
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ToDo")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do{
        //fetching data from coredata
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject]
        {
            //appending the list from the value in coredata (attribute) or entity
            self.list.append(data.value(forKey: "title")as! String)
            print("append success")
        }
    }catch {
        print("failed")
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Everything seems to work except for the UITableViewCell, the print command I entered just to check if the function is executed didn't even work. I tried TableView.reloadData() but it still didn't work. Logically if the problem is with the public function or data source or delegate it won't even generate any rows, but rows are generated. I tried resizing the cell height size too but it still won't work. Please help!

Comment: Add `getData()` method in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Your `TableView` property should be `tableView`; by convention properties and variables start with a lower case letter while types start with a capital

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors with the code:

1. You need to reload once the data fetching from `CoreData` is complete.

```
func getData() {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ToDo")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            self.list.append(data.value(forKey: "title")as! String)
        }
        self.TableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

2. Also, don't forget to call the `getData` function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Routines"
    TableView.delegate = self
    TableView.dataSource = self
    getData()
}
```

Comment: Core data is not asynchronous, and you shouldn't reload the entire table in the `for` loop. It is also better to save the managed object in the array and access the required property in `cellForRow` rather than just storing the property. You are correct that you need to actually call `getData` and reload the table once the data has been fetched.

Comment: You're right. But, I'm not gonna modify his list array though.